# Centering an div which overflows it's parent within another centered div

Tags: css, html, overflow, centering

I have a single column layout where the column is a centered div with a fixed width. I want to place a wider div within the column which overflows it's parents, but center it within the parent. Conceptually something like the following:

```
<div style="width: 100px; margin: 0 auto; overflow:visible;" id="parent">
    <div style="width: 400px; margin 0 auto;" id="child"></div>
</div>
```

The centering works as long as the child div is thinner than its parent, but once it gets larger, it always aligns left with the parent for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="child">Child div</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VrMv/)

When an element overflows his parent, it is normal behaviour that it only overflows to the right. When you, for example, have a site that is wider then the viewport, you never have to scroll left, but only to the right. This solution is based on a absolute centered div, with a negative left margin (that value is the half of his own width). So if you know the width of this element, this solution should be fine.

Tested in FF 3.6, IE7 and IE8

Comment: I want to treat the inner div as a flowable object, though. Is there a way to resume the normal flow model after the element is made absolutely positioned?

Comment: I've updated the jsFiddle code: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/4VrMv/3/)

Use relative positioning to keep the flow (so the height of the child element stretches the parent element)

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I made [a variation](http://jsfiddle.net/JxcRZ/) of Justus' solution. Instead of relative positioning, I used a negative margin of 50% in the inner element.

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
#child {
    margin: 0 -50%;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

This way you don't need to know the element sizes ahead of time.

Comment: hmm this doesn't work for me though. When I use this code and make the #child smaller or wider, the centering goes wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but try giving the parent element a position set to `relative` and child `absolute` and then set `top`, `left` and `width/height` properties for the child div accordingly.

Comment: The problem with absolutely positioning it is that it's removed from the normal flow model and elements will appear under it. Is there a way to resume the normal flow model after an absolutely positioned element?

Comment: The only way to resume the normal flow is to simulate it by making sure that the #wrapper height is the same as the #child height.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve it:

http://jsfiddle.net/WPuhU/1/

Also take care of the scrollbars(they do not appear if your window view is smaller then the overflowing div). Auto centers the overflowing div.

css:

```
#center-3 {height:40px;background-color: #999;}
#center-1 {height:20px;top:10px;background-color: #aaa;}

/* the necesary code */
body {width:100%;margin:0;}
#center-4 {
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;  
    /* remove the next 2 line for a normal flow */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
#center-3 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}
#center-2, #center-1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
#center-2 {
    left: 50%;
}
#center-1 {   
    left: -50%;
}
```

html:

```
 <div id="center-4">
    <div id="center-3">
        <div id="center-2">
            <div id="center-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="other-stuff">Here comes the other stuff above.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
}

#child {
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```